# Mongo Java connecting on invalid host/port, is it really connecting?

Tags: java, mongodb, mongo-java

I have a following code

```
public class MongoService {

    private final Mongo mongo;
    private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(MongoService.class);

    public MongoService() throws UnknownHostException {
        mongo = new Mongo("localhot", 2707);
        DB db = mongo.getDB("contract");
        LOGGER.info(db.getCollection("Test").getName());
    }

    public Mongo getMongoInstance() {
        return mongo;
    }

    public void insert() {
        LOGGER.info("will run mongo insert now");
    }

    public void query() {
        LOGGER.info("will run query now");
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) throws UnknownHostException {
        MongoService mongoService = new MongoService();
        mongoService.insert();
        mongoService.query();

    }
}
```

Output

```
15:26:07.509 [main] INFO  c.s.s.business.persist.MongoService - Test
15:26:07.514 [main] INFO  c.s.s.business.persist.MongoService - will run mongo insert now
15:26:07.514 [main] INFO  c.s.s.business.persist.MongoService - will run query now
```

- The host(should be localhost) and port(should be 27017) is clearly wrong, but when I run this program, it runs and doesn't gives any exceptions
- Is it really connecting?? I am sure no, then how to handle such situations?

Comment: Do you have the right logging level set for the Mongo driver?

Comment: In your log4j config, you could add something like <logger name="com.mongodb"><level value="debug" /></logger>.  I'd be surprised if you don't get some error message there.

Comment: You don't actually try to access the DB, right?   Just print MSG to log?

Comment: getDB() is trying to access the DB in above code

Comment: I tried your exact code and got an expected exception.   What versions are you running?  Are you sure you don't have server named "localhot"? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

mongo.getDB("contract") simply creates a DB Object and put it into mongo-java-driver internal cache.

AFAIK, a connection is obtained from the pool only when a request (ie. an operation as find, insert, ...) is sent to the database.

Try to execute a findOne operation and an IOException should occur :

```
java.io.IOException: couldn't connect to [/127.0.0.1:2017] bc:java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
    at com.mongodb.DBPort._open(DBPort.java:228)
    at com.mongodb.DBPort.go(DBPort.java:112)
    at com.mongodb.DBPort.go(DBPort.java:93)
    at com.mongodb.DBPort.findOne(DBPort.java:146)
    at com.mongodb.DBPort.runCommand(DBPort.java:157)
    at com.mongodb.DBTCPConnector.fetchMaxBsonObjectSize(DBTCPConnector.java:457)
    at com.mongodb.DBTCPConnector.checkMaster(DBTCPConnector.java:444)
    at com.mongodb.DBTCPConnector.call(DBTCPConnector.java:209)
    at com.mongodb.DBApiLayer$MyCollection.__find(DBApiLayer.java:305)
    at com.mongodb.DBCollection.findOne(DBCollection.java:647)
    at com.mongodb.DBCollection.findOne(DBCollection.java:626)
    at com.mongodb.DBCollection.findOne(DBCollection.java:615)
```

Comment: this is what my understanding is , but just wanted to make sure I am thinking correct!, thank you @Benoit for answering

Comment: Is there any other way to find failed/invalid connections?

Comment: Here is another answer in SO : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6832517/how-to-check-from-a-driver-if-mongodb-server-is-running