# MongoDB: check connection to DB

Tags: java, mongodb

I'm looking for best way to check connection to Mongo DB.
Situation: client makes request (api) to server. And server returns status of all databases.

What the best way to do it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I use this:

```
Builder o = MongoClientOptions.builder().connectTimeout(3000);  
MongoClient mongo = new MongoClient(new ServerAddress("192.168.0.1", 3001), o.build());    

try {
  mongo.getAddress();
} catch (Exception e) {
  System.out.println("Mongo is down");
  mongo.close();
  return;
}
```

Comment: The method is deprecated in version 3.9.

Answer (score 7):

In Java MongoDriver 3.3.0 use ServerMonitorListener to determine whether server is up and connected or not.
Here is the example code,

```
public class ServerConnection implements ServerMonitorListener {
    private MongoClient client;

    public ServerConnection(){
        try {
            MongoClientOptions clientOptions = new MongoClientOptions.Builder()
                .addServerMonitorListener(this)
                .build();

            client = new MongoClient(new ServerAddress("localhost", 27017), clientOptions);
        } catch (Exception ex) {

        }
    }

    @Override
    public void serverHearbeatStarted(ServerHeartbeatStartedEvent serverHeartbeatStartedEvent) {
        // Ping Started
    }

    @Override
    public void serverHeartbeatSucceeded(ServerHeartbeatSucceededEvent serverHeartbeatSucceededEvent) {
        // Ping Succeed, Connected to server
    }

    @Override
    public void serverHeartbeatFailed(ServerHeartbeatFailedEvent serverHeartbeatFailedEvent) {
        // Ping failed, server down or connection lost
    }
}
```

Comment: Good one, looking for the place where I could declare such a listener in the new mongodb java async driver... not found yet. MongoClientOptions seems to be replaced by MongoClientSettings which does not have the addServerMonitorListener()

Answer (score 6):

The [ping](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/command/ping/) command is a no-op used to test whether a server is responding to commands. This command will return immediately even if the server is write-locked:

```java
try {
    DBObject ping = new BasicDBObject("ping", "1");
    mongoTemplate.getDb().getMongo().getDB("DATABASE NAME").command(ping);
} catch (Exception exp) {
    // MongoDb is down..
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `MongoClient` for Java, all the info you need is here...

http://docs.mongodb.org/ecosystem/tutorial/getting-started-with-java-driver/

Comment: That is works for me. But strange my DB object does not have serverStatus() method.

Comment: @Lugaru `db.serverStatus()` is a shell command and not part of the MongoDB Java driver

Answer (score 2):

If I understand your question correctly you want to get state returned via a web service call. You can write a function that invokes `db.serverStatus()` and have it return the data. Check out the documentation here:

[Monitoring for MongoDB](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/administration/monitoring/)

Answer (score 1):

Answering: How do I check that my `MongoClient` connected to my db?

As has already been pointed out, the [getting started documentation](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/drivers/java/sync/current/fundamentals/connection/connect/) uses the [ping](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/command/ping/) command.

Packaged as a function:

```java
/**
 * Try to detect if the given MongoDatabase successfully connected to a Mongo
 * instance.
 * 
 * Will block up to the client's socket settings timeout, e.g. 30000 ms.
 * 
 * Returning true indicates that future uses of the given client will probably
 * succeed,
 * but the connection is not guaranteed as connection state may change.
 * 
 * @param database
 * @return the present connection state
 */
static boolean isConnected(MongoDatabase database) {
    Bson command = new BsonDocument("ping", new BsonInt64(1));
    try {
        database.runCommand(command);
    } catch (MongoTimeoutException e) {
        return false;
    }
    return true;

}

/**
 * Try to detect if the given MongoClient successfully connected to a Mongodb
 * instance.
 * 
 * Will block up to the client's socket settings timeout, e.g. 30000 ms.
 * 
 * Returning true indicates that future uses of the given client will probably
 * succeed,
 * but the connection is not guaranteed as connection state may change.
 * 
 * @param mongoClient
 * @return the present connection state
 */
static boolean isConnected(MongoClient mongoClient) {
    return isConnected(mongoClient.getDatabase("admin"));
}
```

`mongoClient.listDatabaseNames().first();` would also work, but that would just run the [listDatabases](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/command/listDatabases/) command against the admin database. So manually writing the ping command is slightly better.

After running a command, [`mongoClient.getClusterDescription()`](https://mongodb.github.io/mongo-java-driver/4.7/apidocs/mongodb-driver-legacy/com/mongodb/MongoClient.html#getClusterDescription()) will return a meaningful result, but it does not block or wait, so calling it right after creating a MongoClient instance will not return an actionable response.

If you need more control, look at the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39294943/8954109) using [ServerMonitorListener](http://mongodb.github.io/mongo-java-driver/4.7/apidocs/mongodb-driver-core/com/mongodb/event/ServerMonitorListener.html).

This answer is valid as of/for `'org.mongodb:mongodb-driver-sync:4.9.1'`