# How can I check for MongoDB's active connections status using Java driver

Tags: java, mongodb, connection-pooling

I have a requirement to publish (to Graphite) the 'number of active connection available' status of a Mongo db instance when a REST service is called. I know we can use db.serverStatus() to know the details of connections on the server side. 
I am looking to get the 'number of active connections available' information on the client side using JAVA API. The MongoDB Java Driver API documentation doesn't help much on it.

Comment: Follow this solution = http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17194268/mongodb-check-connection-to-db/39294943#39294943

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Assuming you are using the 3.0.x driver, and connecting to localhost on default port:

```
MongoClient mongoClient = new MongoClient();
MongoDatabase database = mongoClient.getDatabase("admin");
Document serverStatus = database.runCommand(new Document("serverStatus", 1));
Map connections = (Map) serverStatus.get("connections");
Integer current = (Integer) connections.get("current");
```

Comment: Perfect and Thanks. Thank you  @imakarsh.

Comment: but you get the all connections on the mongo server side, not on the client side... am i right?

Comment: Thanks @ori... In the question he asked "I am looking to get the 'number of active connections available' information on the client side", so I got confused...

Comment: Thanks. I like it a bit more using MongoTemplate and org.bson.Document instead of java.util.Map.
Document serverStatus = mongoTemplate.getDb().runCommand(new Document("serverStatus", 1));
return serverStatus.get("connections", Document.class).getInteger("current").doubleValue();

Answer (score 0):

db.serverStatus() provides information about the number of connections created and number of connections available. Something like below :

```
    "connections" : {
    "current" : 3,
    "available" : 2045,
    "totalCreated" : NumberLong(3)
}
```

You could also use db.currentOp(true) to fetch the in progress details.

http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.currentOp/