# How do I check MongoDB 3.0 Client Connection Status with the Java Driver?

Tags: java, mongodb, database

I am having problems because I only want my code to execute after the MongoClient has successfully made a connection.  But I am having problems finding documentation on this.  Here is my example

```
MongoClientURI connectionString = new MongoClientURI("mongodb://"+mongoUser+":"+mongoPassword+"@"+config.getMongodbHost()+":"+config.getMongodbPort()+"/"+config.getMongodbDatabase());
        mongoClient = new MongoClient(connectionString);
        goldfishDatabase = mongoClient.getDatabase("goldfish");

System.out.println("Don't print this line until the connection has been made.");
```

Comment: Follow this solution := http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17194268/mongodb-check-connection-to-db/39294943#39294943

Answer (score 1):

The driver maintains a connection pool. So a general problem should make

```
mongoClient = new MongoClient( connectionString )
```

throw an exception, a MongoException, specifically. After that, if a connection is needed, the driver provides a connection.

Let's assume the database gets down at some point after the call to `new MongoClient()`. Then, the operation which needs a connection would fail, in case of write operations with a [MongoWriteException](http://api.mongodb.org/java/3.0/com/mongodb/MongoWriteException.html). Read operations will fail with a [MongoSocketReadException](http://api.mongodb.org/java/3.0/com/mongodb/MongoSocketReadException.html), or with a [MongoReadTimeoutException](http://api.mongodb.org/java/3.0/com/mongodb/MongoSocketReadTimeoutException.html). Have a detailed look in the [MongoException API docs](http://api.mongodb.org/java/3.0/com/mongodb/MongoException.html).

Note that these are all Runtime exceptions, and hence are unchecked aren't enforced to be caught. However, runtime exceptions can be caught like any other exception

```
try {
  mongoClient = new MongoClient( connectionString )
} catch (MongoException me) {
  // handle exception
}
```

So unless an exception is thrown, assume everything to be in a consistent state - which is the Java way.

Comment: The problem is that my processing occurs even without a connection. I rather have a connection test in the beginning to see if there is a reachable database.  Like a ping of some sort.

Comment: If you catch the exceptions like shown, I rather doubt that your processing will run. However, of course you can do a `mongoClient.getDatabaseNames()` or similar periodically and fire an event or something like that...

Answer (score -1):

In JavaScript, you can just print out the error.

```
    try{
        mongoose.connection('connetion url');
    }catch(error){
        console.log(error);
    }
```