# When does the mongo ping Diagnostic command ever return { ok: 0 }?

Tags: java, mongodb, scala

I had to write a basic health check for one of the mongo DB and while sifting through their official [docs](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/command/ping/) and other resources (like [this](https://serverfault.com/questions/625492/how-to-construct-a-mongodb-health-check-in-haproxy/625493#625493) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17194268/mongodb-check-connection-to-db)) I learn that `ping` command is the way to go about it (bc it is lightweight). Now my question is whether the response for the ping command will always be `{ok: 1}`? Under what circumstances will the ping response return `{ok:0}`? Can anyone shed some light on it? Currently, I've implemented to catch the exception which is shown below but will there be any cases when the ping response will return `OK:0`?

```
      val command: Document = new Document("ping", 1)
      // ping the db
      val pingResponse = mongoClient.getDatabase("DBNAME").runCommand(command)
      // check for the ping response to be {"ok": 1.0 }
      if (pingResponse.get("ok").equals(1.0)) {   // IS THIS CONDITION NEEDED ? 
                                                  // WILL THIS BE EVER OK:0 ?
        // return healthy
      } else {

      // DO I NEED THIS CONDITION? EVER?? TO RETURN UNHEALTHY?
      // return unHealthy
      }
    } catch {
      case e: Exception =>
        // MUCH NEEDED UNHEALTHY CONDITION
        // return unHealthy
```

Thanks.

Comment: There are Scala drivers for MongoDB, rather than using plain old Java one ...

Comment: @cchantep And those drivers would return ping response as {OK:0} ?

Comment: The behaviour of the DB about ping command is well described in the mongo documentation. On this other side if you choose to execute such command from a Scala app, using a Scala driver seems "useful"

Comment: @cchantep - Could you point where the doc says when the ping command response could be ```{OK:0}```? https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/command/ping/ ?

Answer (score 0):

You can get InterruptedAtShutdown (code 11600) if you run ping in an infinite loop and stop the server.