# How to check if a Mongo repository is up and running

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, spring-mvc

I want to make a service that checks if a Mongo repository is up and running.

What would be the equivalent of `SELECT 1 FROM DUAL` from Oracle for a quick select?

I'm using Spring Data (`org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.query.Query` class). I would like not to use an existing collection in the database for this check, e.g, **if possible**, I would like not to count elements from a collection.

Comment: What do you mean by a `Mongo Repository is up and running`. Only Mongo Instances can be running bound to a repository. Do you wish to check if a connection can be established to a database?

Comment: @BatScream yes, exactly that.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how to check from a driver, if mongoDB server is running](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6832517/how-to-check-from-a-driver-if-mongodb-server-is-running)